# Magento: Brand Category Product Description

Tags: magento

I was wondering how this sites make this possible:
you can reach a product category like

```
http://www.example.de/Uhren/
```

and if you click in the sidebar on Adidas, you came to the url

```
http://www.example.de/brand/Uhren/
```

with a specific text about adidas watches. How can this done with magento? With two categories?

I have another site, same function:

```
http://schuhe.example.de/brand-lederschuhe/
```

if you click on a brand it becomes

```
http://schuhe.example.de/damenschuhe-brand-lederschuhe/
```

Maybe it´s simpler than I think, don´t know..

Comment: They probably just use the built-in URL rewrite managment of Magento.

Comment: Do you think they have a main category and a "brand" category?

Comment: I can't tell what they do. If I had to do it, I'd use extra brand categories if it are many brands and products, but only use a filter and no extra categories, if it's just a couple of brands.

Comment: Often category structures and the product associations are created by a script, mostly as part of an ERP integration. Categories are the simplest way to achieve this desired effect.